# Is there a bug in TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, timespan

This will output "0":

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Zero;
span.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
Console.WriteLine(span.TotalSeconds);   ----->
```

However, this will output "300":

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Zero.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
Console.WriteLine(span.TotalSeconds);   ----->
```

Is this a known bug?

Comment: John's answer is correct, it's not a bug. However, I think the description of the method can be misleading, particularly to those new to C# and/or the concept of an immutable struct. "Adds the specified System.TimeSpan to this instance" is an unfortunate wording, because I can see how someone might get the impression that the value would be modified.

Comment: So, @Anthony: you've reported the documentation problem?

Comment: I only just now paid attention to it! I could report it, let them determine if it's worth changing it.

Comment: @John, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/599964/potentially-misleading-descriptions-on-methods-of-timespan-struct

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[`TimeSpan.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx) does not modify the input - it returns a new `TimeSpan` which is the input plus the addend:

> #### Remarks
>
> The return value must be between
> TimeSpan.MinValue and
> TimeSpan.MaxValue; otherwise, an
> exception is thrown.
>
> The return value is a new TimeSpan;
> the original TimeSpan is not modified.

Comment: It even says that in the documentation for TimeSpan.Add (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx): The return value is a new TimeSpan; the original TimeSpan is not modified.

Comment: However, it should be noted that it’s not *because* `TimeSpan` is a struct. It’s because `TimeSpan` is *immutable*. `System.Drawing.Point` is an example of a struct that is not immutable. `string` is an example of an immutable type that is not a struct.

Comment: -1 for unrelated and misleading "`Timespan` is a struct" phrase.

Answer (score -3):

Not a bug in Timespan but.... in the way structures get copied in C#.

Comment: @John Saunders: Don't think this deserves a down vote.  The answer does state that it is not a bug.  Pretty much the same answer you gave just a lot more brief.

Comment: It would be a bug if Timespan was a class, but as a struct this is expected behaviour. That is, classes are passed by reference, so whatever the receiving method does to the passed class are visible at a calling level. A struct however is passed by value, so receiving methods cannot communicate changes made to the passed in method. To communicate changed values either out parameters or return values need to be used.

Comment: @Dieter, TomTom let TimeSpan off the hook only to put C# structs in a bag and then hang them all. If not worth a downvote, the answer clearly begs for more detail.

Comment: @Tim, pass by reference/value has nothing to do with this. Struct vs. Class has nothing to do with this. This is about immutability. It is perfectly legal (however frowned upon) to create a mutable struct and have a method on that struct modify it. TimeSpan is not such a struct.

Comment: In fact, it’s not even directly because of immutability. It’s simply because of the contract of the `TimeSpan.Add` method. Of course, in the case of `TimeSpan` that contract was chosen in order to achieve immutability — but you could equally well have a similar `Add` method on a type that is otherwise mutable.